# How to allow MySQL on Windows Server for external remote access?

Tags: php, mysql, windows-server-2008-r2

i have installed xampp on my windows server 2008 R2. I'm running a script there that stores me data over the day. Now i want to retrieve the data from my own computer or just external by connecting the database via mysql_connect("hostname","username","pw"). after some research i have got told that i have to commend

```
> [...]
> #bind-address = 127.0.0.1
> #skip-networking 
  [...]
```

in /etc/mysql/my.cnf

didn't find the my.cf file in mysql but found one in xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini .
But when i opened the file i found the lines even commented so hadn't got to change anything..... strange.

then i got told to create a new user with the host setted %. So i did. now i tried to acces the database on my pc (xampp) but when i want to connect the database, i just get the error message, that the connection failured.
Where is the mistake ?

thanks

edit:

thats howi exactly connect

```
$connection=mysql_connect("hostname","usrname","password")or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("dbname")or die(mysql_error());
```

and the error message i get is german you can trabslate.

Warning: mysql_connect(): Ein Verbindungsversuch ist fehlgeschlagen, da die Gegenstelle nach einer bestimmten Zeitspanne nicht richtig reagiert hat, oder die hergestellte Verbindung war fehlerhaft, da der verbundene Host nicht reagiert hat. in C:\xampp\htdocs\tickerdata\get.php on line 4

just means as much as connection failured because remote didnt react in certain time period or connection was faulty because host didnt react...

Comment: Can you give us the exact error message? The "my.ini" file is correct for a windows machine (the "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" file would be on a Linux machine). The MySQL user with a host of `%` means that that user can log in from anywhere, not just localhost.

Comment: 1. "usrname" is spelled "username", im not sure if this would help but its worth a glance :\ have you tried googling this problem? (even just the error message) there is usually someone who has an answer :\

Comment: [one question from stack overflow that might help...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837051/mysql-connection-string-using-php)

Comment: @A_Wheel thanks the question is helping to isolate my problem a bit more. they discussing about the firewall on my server. that could block the mysql port (3306). You guys know anything about setting that port free? or should i set it free?

Comment: its a port isolated to just MySQL so as long as you are using the port for database access you will need it free. check [here...(list of UDP + TCP port numbers )](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can't connect to the server remotely, but you can connect locally, you either need to open port 3306 in the firewall, or grant the user permissions from the remote IP.

The port should be opened in the windows firewall, as well as the **router firewall**.  Your router will need to forward the port to the 2008R2 server.

To open ports in 2008R2 firewall:

http://www.2x.com/blog/2010/04/tech/configuring-the-windows-server-2008-r2-firewall-to-open-ports-for-2x-solutions/

To grant user permissions on IP:

```
GRANT ALL ON foo.* TO bar@'255.255.255.255' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```

Keep in mind that it is possible to have duplicate usernames in MySQL, and if you didn't create the new user with a UNIQUE username then you may be getting the privileges of the user jailed to localhost